# Would it be on-topic to ask whether the NHS of the UK is wrong about when to call the emergency number?

Tags: support

The [UK's NHS page on heart palpitations](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/heart-palpitations/) says at the top:

> Heart palpitations are when your heartbeat becomes more noticeable."

and says in the middle:

> Heart palpitations are common and not usually a sign of anything serious.
>
> Common causes include:
>
> - strenuous exercise
> - [...]

and says at the bottom:

> Call 999 or go to A&E if:
>
> You currently have heart palpitations with any of these symptoms:
>
> - chest pain
> - shortness of breath
> - feeling faint or fainting

Since strenuous exercise causes heart palpitations with shortness of breath in any healthy person, the implication is that person should call 999 or go to A&E every time they undergo some strenuous exercise.

Would it be on-topic to ask about this?

Comment: I am puzzled by the downvote. How could I make this question better: both or either this one on Skeptics Meta and the hypothetical one I could conceivably ask on Skeptics?

Answer (score 4):

No, it wouldn't be appropriate to ask a question here, because *you don't have a question*.

You don't have any doubt. There is nothing that we need to research and produce empirical evidence to support.

You've found a poorly-worded piece of advice. (One that is unlikely to actually cause confusion, and if it does, it is erring towards safety.)

By all means, contact the NHS and ask them to make the wording clearer, but there is no value in having the community research the fact that your heartbeat becomes more noticeable when you exercise.

Comment: "You don't have any doubt. There is nothing that we need to research and produce empirical evidence to support." There is no way you could know that I had no doubt (what a strange thing to read on Skeptics Meta), and in fact, I did, and more than I do now, thanks to your answer and its upvotes. I am not a doctor and would always have doubt when alone (as far as I knew) feeling skeptical about a doctors medical advice or in this case, an NHS webpage giving it, which was presumably written by a doctor, or at least approved by one). It seemed crazy, but why not to the NHS, then? And you seem 1/

Comment: with your, "(One that is unlikely to actually cause confusion, and if it does, it is erring towards safety.)" to think it is *not* likely to cause confusion, so surely I was right to wonder why *I* was so confused by it. How can I know I am right? I didn't even know what "heart palpitations" meant until about an hour before posting my question. I had guessed it meant maybe fibrillations, but I'm still not sure what they are. I was sure heart palpitations are bad, but they are actually *good*, if caused by mild exercise, right? 2/

Comment: Let me try making some statements that (a) I believe are clearly true, and (b) I believe that you believe are clearly true, to see if we can identify the confusion here. Tell me if you have doubts over any of these statements: 1) Exercise is good for you (in moderation) and is recommended by doctors in most cases.  2) Strenuous exercise causes your heart to beat faster, and you can often feel it. 3) Strenuous exercise causes shortness of breath. [cont'd]

Comment: Why wasn't sexual orgasm mentioned as a cause of heart palpitations in the web page then? They would be one of the most common causes of heart palpitations, and would also be good, by which I mean, healthy? You said it was poorly worded advice. Really? I thought it was crystal clear plain English. The only medical jargon, "heart palpitations" was explained clearly in plain English (and correctly according to you). How do you think it should have been worded? How is it erring on the side of safety? "No, it wouldn't be appropriate to ask a question here, because you don't have a question." 3/

Comment: 4) Fast heart beats and shortness of breath after strenuous exercise are expected; they are not symptoms of health problems and shouldn't result in ER visits. 5) Fast heart beats and shortness of breath WITHOUT any clear, healthy cause, such as strenuous exercise is unusual in a healthy person. 6) The NHS want you to get medical attention in such cases.

Comment: "crystal clear plain English" That's irrelevant if you found it confusing. "How do you think it should have been worded?" That's not my job, but they seem to use heart palpitations to mean a fast heart beat due to any cause, and also a fast heart beat to unknown causes.

Comment: "How is it erring on the side of safety?" I think that is clear, so this is making me wonder if there is any point continuing. If people are confused by the wording to think that heart palpitations caused by exercise are bad, if they followed the advice, they would go to ER. That is wasteful, but safer than confused people with real symptoms concluding they should not see a doctor.

Comment: I think "here" logically means on Skeptics, and I can see how it might seem that I don't have a question because it seems like I should just know that I am right here, but if you mean on Skeptics Meta, then that would seem strange, because clearly I do have a question about whether it's on topic, and you do not say that it is either on or off topic or "not applicable". So I wonder about the somewhat outraged tone of your answer, which make me think that you think I should have not even asked about the ontopicness. That line of thinking would lead to the puzzling downvote on my question. 4/4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148357/discussion-between-matthew-christopher-bartsh-and-oddthinking).